# passing argument 2 of strcpy makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, linked-list, strcpy

this is the whole code of what im doing, im trying to create a song library that will put what the user enter into file. now the compiler says that passing argument 2 of strcpy makes pointer from integer without a cast and i dont know why. also can u check my linked list for the struct. im so noob at linked list :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

struct node {
    //definition of struct node to create struct node song
    int SongID;
    char Title[100];
    char Artist[100];
    char Composer[100];
    char Album[100];
    char Genre[100];
    int Rating;
    char Remarks[1000];
    struct node*next;
};

add_song(int SongID, char Title, char Artist, char Composer, char Album, char Genre, int Rating, char Remarks) {
    //this is the add song function as stated in the mp2 specs
    FILE*fp;
    fp=fopen("song.txt","r+");

    int i=1, j, choice;
    struct node* temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temp->SongID=SongID;
    fprintf(fp,"%d",SongID);

    strcpy(temp->Title, Title);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",Title);

    strcpy(temp->Artist, Artist);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",Artist);

    strcpy(temp->Composer, Composer);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",Composer);

    strcpy(temp->Album, Album);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",Album);

    strcpy(temp->Genre, Genre);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",Genre);

    temp->Rating=Rating;
    fprintf(fp,"%d",Rating);

    strcpy(temp->Remarks, Remarks);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",Remarks);

    fclose(fp);
}

int main ()
{
    struct node song;
    int choice;
    int k, i;
    int SongID;
    char Title[100];
    char Artist[100];
    char Composer[100];
    char Album[100];
    char Genre[100];
    int Rating;
    char Remarks[1000];

   /* do
     {
        printf("Enter 1 to add song, 2 to update song, or 3 to list songs: ");
        scanf("%d\n", &choice1);

        if (choice1==1)
        {*/
        srand(time(NULL));
        song.SongID=rand();

        printf("Enter Title: ");
        fgets(Title,100,stdin);

        printf("Enter Artist: ");
        fgets(Artist,100,stdin);

        printf("Enter Composer: ");
        fgets(Composer,100,stdin);

        printf("Enter Album: ");
        fgets(Album,100,stdin);

        //for easier code, numbers are being chosen as input
        printf("Press 1 for Art Music, 2 for Popular Music, or 3 for Traditional Music): ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice==1)
        {
            strcpy(song.Genre,"Art Music");
        }
        else if (choice==2)
        {
            strcpy(song.Genre,"Popular Music");
        }
        else if (choice==3)
        {
            strcpy(song.Genre,"Traditional Music");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You entered a blank genre.\n");
        }

        printf("Enter your rating, choose from 1-5: ");
        scanf("%d", &Rating);

        printf("Enter Remarks: ");
        fgets(Remarks,1000,stdin);

        add_song(SongID, Title, Artist, Composer, Album, Genre, Rating, Remarks);
            /*k=0;
            break;
        }
        else if (choice1==2)
        {
            //update_song(song);
            k=0;
            break;
        }
        else if (choice1==3)
        {
           // list_songs(song);
            k=0;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            k=1;
            printf("That is not a valid input.\n");
        }
    }while (k==1);*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `add_song(int SongID, char Title, char Artist, char Composer, char Album, char Genre, int Rating, char Remarks)` should be `void add_song(int SongID, char *Title, char *Artist, char *Composer, char *Album, char *Genre, int Rating, char *Remarks)`. They are strings, not single `char`s.

Comment: change to `void add_song(int SongID, char* Title, char* Artist, char* Composer, char* Album, char* Genre, int Rating, char* Remarks)`

Comment: what compiler were you using that you didn't get drowned with warnings for that? no return type, passing char to a function that expects char *...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working copy of your code except one thing "Remark". Before executing scanf for Remark process exits . Change your arguments as I did here and also change fopen mode as +w so if file is not exist it can be created automatically. strcpy prototype is `char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src).
So I have changed accordingly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

struct node {
    //definition of struct node to create struct node song
    int SongID;
    char Title[100];
    char Artist[100];
    char Composer[100];
    char Album[100];
    char Genre[100];
    int Rating;
    char Remarks[1000];
    struct node *next;
};

void add_song(int SongID, char *Title, char *Artist, char *Composer, char *Album, char *Genre, int Rating, char *Remarks) {

    //this is the add song function as stated in the mp2 specs
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("song.txt","a+");

    int i=1, j, choice;
    struct node* temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temp->SongID=SongID;
    fprintf(fp,"%d",SongID);

    strcpy(temp->Title, Title);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",Title);

    strcpy(temp->Artist, Artist);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",Artist);

    strcpy(temp->Composer, Composer);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",Composer);

    strcpy(temp->Album, Album);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",Album);

    strcpy(temp->Genre, Genre);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",Genre);

    temp->Rating=Rating;
    fprintf(fp,"%d",Rating);

    strcpy(temp->Remarks, Remarks);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",Remarks);

    fclose(fp);
}

int main ()
{
    struct node song;
    int choice;
    int k, i;
    int SongID;
    char Title[100];
    char Artist[100];
    char Composer[100];
    char Album[100];
    char Genre[100];
    int Rating;
    char Remarks[1000];

   /* do
     {
        printf("Enter 1 to add song, 2 to update song, or 3 to list songs: ");
        scanf("%d\n", &choice1);

        if (choice1==1)
        {*/
        srand(time(NULL));
        song.SongID=rand();

        printf("Enter Title: ");
        fgets(Title,100,stdin);

        printf("Enter Artist: ");
        fgets(Artist,100,stdin);

        printf("Enter Composer: ");
        fgets(Composer,100,stdin);

        printf("Enter Album: ");
        fgets(Album,100,stdin);

        //for easier code, numbers are being chosen as input
        printf("Press 1 for Art Music, 2 for Popular Music, or 3 for Traditional Music): ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice==1)
        {

            strcpy(song.Genre,"Art Music");
        }
        else if (choice==2)
        {

             strcpy(song.Genre,"Popular Music");
        }
        else if (choice==3)
        {

            strcpy(song.Genre,"Traditional Music");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You entered a blank genre.\n");
        }

        printf("Enter your rating, choose from 1-5: ");
        scanf("%d",&Rating);

        printf("Enter Remarks: \n");
        fgets(Remarks,1000,stdin);

        add_song(SongID, Title, Artist, Composer, Album, Genre, Rating, Remarks);
            /*k=0;
            break;
        }
        else if (choice1==2)
        {
            //update_song(song);
            k=0;
            break;
        }
        else if (choice1==3)
        {
           // list_songs(song);
            k=0;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            k=1;
            printf("That is not a valid input.\n");
        }
    }while (k==1);*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you i did what u said, but the problem here is that i cant use w+ because it overwrites the file, and i need to put all the things that the users entered without the other things entered before being overwritten and the problem here i think is the linked list, although i haven't implemented linked list yet, i dont know how do i do it here

Comment: I guess you want want to append changes at last .So you can use a+ mode . I update my answer as per it

Comment: i dont know if this might be related to your code but when i open the txt file, it isn't responding

Comment: I am ready to help :-).Can you tell me please not responding means what do you mean ? I have already compiled and its working for me .

Comment: i solved it already, but the problem now is when i removed the comment for the statements in main, the thing that happens with remarks (where it skips the remarks part) happened with the title too i dont know why

Comment: so i noticed that it skips the first and last fgets

Answer (score 1):

Your function definition don't match with the arguments you pass. It should be

```
    void add_song(int SongID, char *Title, char *Artist, char *Composer, \
char *Album, char *Genre, int Rating, char *Remarks) {

       ...
       ...
    }
```

Another issue is that `songID` is uninitialized in `main()`. Reading from an uninitialized variable is [undefind behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Another problem you might face is that `fgets()` reads the newline `\n` into buffer if there's space available which might be problematic.
Something to be aware of and you need trim it if nececcary.

Comment: i dont really get the newline buffer thing would u mind explaining it further because im new at c sorry, but i did what you told me and there are only 2 errors left

Comment: When you read a string like `"abc"` using `fgets()`, it's actually `"abc\n"`. This may or may not be an issue. But it actually reads in the newline if there's buffer space.

Comment: based on what i know, scanf doesn't read space and fgets would be better so i used it, can u suggest a better function for this one?

Comment: @shiiranyan `fgets()` *is* better than `scanf()`. You are fine to use `fgets()`. I am just saying if you don't need the newline, you can trim it. For example, after each call to fgets(), you can do: `char *p = strchr(my_array, '\n'); if (p)  *p = 0;` to remove the newline.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't go through the whole code, but strcpy problem is obvious. According to definition of function strcpy (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm), it expects two char pointers (aka strings in C)

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
```

You're passing only char arguments to a function add_song, which is just not the pointer. Change the signature of the function add_song and then you should be fine with strcpy

Comment: so in here strcpy(temp->Title, Title) for example, i need to make Title a pointer?

Comment: Well, yes. But as I and others already suggested, your main problem is that you are actually passing only `char`s into `add_song` (actually a really weird `char`s, that is first 4 bytes of value of those pointers) - you need to actually pass `char` pointers into `add_song` (by having correct definition of `char *` in a `add_song` header. Once you do that, then you will actually already have pointers inside `add_song` function and don't need to change anything in `strcpy` calls